# How can I ignore error message in lex/yacc

Tags: linux, yacc, lex

I defined some rules for operation between two integers, If the input string(3+-2) are not match the rule, it will always output "syntax error" and exit, what I want is dont output anything, could some one can help?

Because I need to integrate this script in my project and dont want to output the error msg("syntax error") defined in related .tab.c file.

Does any solution on this?

Comment: You can ignore all unmatched input, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063455/ignoring-errors-in-yacc-lex

Comment: Thanks John, I'm a freshman to lex/yacc. I used that solution but got compile failure when "bison -d parseYacc.y" and the error msg is "parseYacc.y:44.1: symbol . is used, but is not defined as a token and has no rules". do you know why and related code would be fine.

Comment: I already find the easiest solution, just re-write the yyerror() method.